# difference between StratifiedKFold and StratifiedShuffleSplit in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, cross-validation

As from the title I am wondering what is the difference between

[StratifiedKFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) with the parameter `shuffle=True`

```
StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
```

and

[StratifiedShuffleSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html)

```
StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=10, test_size=’default’, train_size=None, random_state=0)
```

and what is the advantage of using StratifiedShuffleSplit

Comment: mmm in StratifiedShuffleSplit you can set the number of splits... from the sklearn webpage: StratifiedShuffleSplit : This cross-validation object is a merge of StratifiedKFold and ShuffleSplit, which returns stratified randomized folds. The folds are made by preserving the percentage of samples for each class.

Comment: Aah yes, my bad. But still its written in the StratifiedShuffleSplit documentation you linked that "This cross-validation object is a merge of StratifiedKFold and ShuffleSplit, which returns stratified randomized folds. The folds are made by preserving the percentage of samples for each class."

Comment: Difference is between folds (data don't overlap in folds). Whereas in StratifiedShuffleSplit it can and will overlap. See the examples given on the documentation pages to understand it better. Specifically test data. In StratifiedKFold it will always be different in each fold. And in StratifiedShuffleSplit it can be repeatative.

Comment: So if I have to choose between the two I should go for StratifiedKFold isn't it? I do not see the advantage of using the StratifiedShiffleSplit...but there should be because is a more recent function of sklearn... that's way I am wondering

Comment: Sounds like `StratifiedKFold` samples without replacement while `StratifiedShiffleSplit` shuffles with. So, one advantage of `StratifiedShiffleSplit` is you can sample as many times as you want. Sure, individual samples will have overlap -- so any fitted models on the samples will be correlated -- but you can fit many more models, and with more data per model.

Comment: Let's think about it this way. `StratifiedKFold` is the true cross-validation. However, `StratifiedShiffleSplit` is a "generator", and it randomly generate different "train-test" splits for `n_splits` times.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

In `stratKFolds`, each test set should not overlap, even when shuffle is included. With `stratKFolds` and `shuffle=True`, the data is shuffled once at the start, and then divided into the number of desired splits. The test data is always one of the splits, the train data is the rest.

In `ShuffleSplit`, the data is shuffled every time, and then split. This means the test sets may overlap between the splits.

See this block for an example of the difference. Note the overlap of the elements in the test sets for `ShuffleSplit`.

```
splits = 5

tx = range(10)
ty = [0] * 5 + [1] * 5

from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit, StratifiedKFold
from sklearn import datasets

stratKfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=splits, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
shufflesplit = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=splits, random_state=42, test_size=2)

print("stratKFold")
for train_index, test_index in stratKfold.split(tx, ty):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)

print("Shuffle Split")
for train_index, test_index in shufflesplit.split(tx, ty):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
```

Output:

```
stratKFold
TRAIN: [0 2 3 4 5 6 7 9] TEST: [1 8]
TRAIN: [0 1 2 3 5 7 8 9] TEST: [4 6]
TRAIN: [0 1 3 4 5 6 8 9] TEST: [2 7]
TRAIN: [1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9] TEST: [0 5]
TRAIN: [0 1 2 4 5 6 7 8] TEST: [3 9]
Shuffle Split
TRAIN: [8 4 1 0 6 5 7 2] TEST: [3 9]
TRAIN: [7 0 3 9 4 5 1 6] TEST: [8 2]
TRAIN: [1 2 5 6 4 8 9 0] TEST: [3 7]
TRAIN: [4 6 7 8 3 5 1 2] TEST: [9 0]
TRAIN: [7 2 6 5 4 3 0 9] TEST: [1 8]
```

As for when to use them, I tend to use `stratKFolds` for any cross validation, and I use `ShuffleSplit` with a split of 2 for my train/test set splits. But I'm sure there are other use cases for both.

Comment: +1 For your great answer. Can you please, answer [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62174112/why-we-should-call-split-function-during-passing-stratifiedkfold-as-a-parame)

Answer (score 80):

@Ken Syme already has a very good answer. I just want to add something.

- **`StratifiedKFold`** is a variation of `KFold`. First, `StratifiedKFold` shuffles your data, after that splits the data into `n_splits` parts and Done. 
  Now, it will use each part as a test set. Note that **it only and always shuffles data one time** before splitting.

With  `shuffle = True`, the data is shuffled by your `random_state`. Otherwise, 
the data is shuffled by `np.random` (as default).
For example, with `n_splits = 4`, and your data has 3 classes (label) for `y` (dependent variable). 4 test sets cover all the data without any overlap.

[image]

- On the other hand, **`StratifiedShuffleSplit`** is a variation of `ShuffleSplit`.
  First, `StratifiedShuffleSplit` shuffles your data, and then it also splits the data into `n_splits` parts. However, it's not done yet. After this step, `StratifiedShuffleSplit` picks one part to use as a test set.
  Then it repeats the same process `n_splits - 1` other times, to get `n_splits - 1` other test sets. Look at the picture below, with the same data, but this time, the 4 test sets do not cover all the data, i.e there are overlaps among test sets.

[image]

So, the difference here is that `StratifiedKFold` **just shuffles and splits once, therefore the test sets do not overlap**, while `StratifiedShuffleSplit` **shuffles each time before splitting, and it splits `n_splits` times, the test sets can overlap**.

- **Note**: the two methods uses "stratified fold" (that why "stratified" appears in both names). It means each part preserves the same percentage of samples of each class (label) as the original data. You can read more at [cross_validation documents](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation)

Comment: Perfect explanation !!

Answer (score 15):

Output examples of KFold, StratifiedKFold, StratifiedShuffleSplit:
[image: Output examples of KFold, StratifiedKFold, StratifiedShuffleSplit]

The above pictorial output is an extension of `@Ken Syme`'s code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, StratifiedKFold, StratifiedShuffleSplit
SEED = 43
SPLIT = 3

X_train = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
y_train = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]   # note 6,7,8 are labelled class '1'

print("KFold, shuffle=False (default)")
kf = KFold(n_splits=SPLIT, random_state=SEED)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X_train, y_train):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)

print("KFold, shuffle=True")
kf = KFold(n_splits=SPLIT, shuffle=True, random_state=SEED)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X_train, y_train):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)

print("\nStratifiedKFold, shuffle=False (default)")
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=SPLIT, random_state=SEED)
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X_train, y_train):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    
print("StratifiedKFold, shuffle=True")
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=SPLIT, shuffle=True, random_state=SEED)
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X_train, y_train):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    
print("\nStratifiedShuffleSplit")
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=SPLIT, random_state=SEED, test_size=3)
for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X_train, y_train):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)

print("\nStratifiedShuffleSplit (can customise test_size)")
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=SPLIT, random_state=SEED, test_size=2)
for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X_train, y_train):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
```