# When should I shuffle in StratifiedKFold

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, cross-validation

I have read some posts on various CV approaches. But what I don't understand is why shuffling the data in the function leads to significant increase in accuracy and when it is correct to do it.

In my times series dataset of size `921 *10080` where each row is a time series of water temperature of a particular location in an area and the 2 last columns being the labels with 2 groups, ie. high risk(high bacteria level in water) and low risk(low bacteria bacteria in water), accuracy varies very differently based on if I set `"shuffle=True"(achieved accuracy of around 75%)`, versus `accuracy of 50%` when setting `"shuffle=False"` in `StratifiedKFold` as shown below:

```
n_folds = 5
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=n_folds, shuffle=True)
```

The sklearn documentations states the following:

> A note on shufﬂing
>
> If the data ordering is not arbitrary (e.g. samples with the same class label are contiguous), shufﬂing it ﬁrst may be essential to get a meaningful cross- validation result. However, the opposite may be true if the samples are not independently and identically distributed. For example, if samples correspond to news articles, and are ordered by their time of publication, then shufﬂing the data will likely lead to a model that is overﬁt and an inﬂated validation score: it will be tested on samples that are artiﬁcially similar (close in time) to training samples.
>
> Some cross validation iterators, such as KFold, have an inbuilt option to shufﬂe the data indices before splitting them. Note that:
>
> • This consumes less memory than shufﬂing the data directly.
>
> • By default no shufﬂing occurs, including for the (stratiﬁed) K fold cross- validation performed by specifying cv=some_integer to cross_val_score, grid search, etc. Keep in mind that train_test_split still returns a random split.
>
> • The random_state parameter defaults to None, meaning that the shufﬂing will be different every time KFold(..., shuffle=True) is iterated. However, GridSearchCV will use the same shufﬂing for each set of parameters validated by a single call to its fit method.
>
> • To get identical results for each split, set random_state to an integer.

I am not sure if I interpret the documentation correctly- an explanation is much appreciated. Besides, I have a few questions:

1)Why is there such huge improvement in accuracy after shuffling? Am I overfitting? When should I shuffle?

2)Given that all samples are collected from the same area, they are probably not independent. How does this affect shuffling? Is it still valid to shuffle?

3)Does shuffling separate the labels from their corresponding `X` data? (Answer update : No. Shuffling does not separate labels from their corresponding `X` data)

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite tricky and probably it is better placed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

> In my times series dataset of size 921 *10080 where each row is a time series of water temperature of a particular location in an area and the last column being the label with 2 groups

Aren't you using using a classification problem with timeseries futures? You are using dependeten variables (timeseries of the water temperature)  to predict a label. For me this sounds risky, and I would assume that there is not a good chance to predict the label. Just one scenario to think about:

```
Location  Time1 Time2 Time3  Label
A         3       2    1      1
B         100     99   98     1
C         98      99   100    0
```

So in this example label 1 is a timeseries which goes down and label 0 is a timeseries that goes up, but I would bet every classifier has a problem to learn it without connecting the trending component of your columns.

To come back to your question, this can help you to understand shuffling: [difference between StratifiedKFold and StratifiedShuffleSplit in sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969390/difference-between-stratifiedkfold-and-stratifiedshufflesplit-in-sklearn)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sorry I forgot to mention that I was using a neural network model. Hopefully it can extract some useful patterns with multiple hidden layers. I read the post which had explained the different shuffling methods, but still couldn't figure out the reason behind the huge difference in accuracy with and without shuffling:/

Answer (score 1):

When working with time series data you are correct that shuffling will inflate the accuracy. The reason is because shuffling the training set will cause it to contain samples that are very similar to samples found in the test set.

For example, if you trained a model from 2010-2019 and then predicted on 2020, all of the test set samples would be separate in time from the training period so there would be no leakage of information. Now lets say that there was an extreme event in 2020 and you shuffle the data. The training set will now contain samples of that extreme event from some sensors and then in the test set it will learn to predict a similar label for the other sensors during that period. This is a leakage of information between the training and test sets.