# Stratified Train/Test-split in scikit-learn using an attribute

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I need to split my data into a training set (80%) and test set (20%). I currently do that with the code below:

```py
StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=10,test_size=.2, train_size=.8, random_state=0)
```

How ever i need to specify a particular attribute for spliting. I am not able to do it

Comment: I'm not sure my answer is exactly what you are looking for. What do you mean "using an attribute for splitting". Moreover, are you attempting a simple 80/20 split or a K-fold split?

Comment: Please add more details about your data and how you are trying to split it. RIght now, it's not totally clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to split your data in an 80/20 stratified manner, I recommend using  [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html):

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True, stratify=y, random_state=0)
# Stratification is done based on the y labels
```

If you need to use [StratifiedShuffleSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.split), you can do the following:

```py
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=10, test_size=.2, random_state=0)

for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X, y):
     X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
     y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
     # Stratification is done based on the y labels
     # You can use training and test sets within this for loop
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59674072/sklearns-class-stratifiedshufflesplit).