# How to combine two or three feature extraction methods?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to combine two feature extraction methods and classify in python.I am using sklearn.But the accuracy is not improved.What is wrong?How to combine two numpy arrays of feature extraction methods to improve accuracy?Please answer the way to combine in order to improve accuracy.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us the code you used?

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary that every time you add a new `feature`, the `accuracy` of your model increases. So, it is necessary that you set up `local cross-validation`. Data science is all about experimenting. The more you experiment, the better results you *might* get.

Comment: I use cross-validation,StratifiedShuffleSplit.

Comment: I will suggest you use `StratifiedKFold`. For the difference and utility, check out this post - https://stackoverflow.com/q/45969390/8293309 .