# use StratifiedShuffleSplit in cross_val_predict (sklearn)

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to use supervised machine learning to predict the weight of crop (e.g. potatoes) from their respective length and width measures. Before fitting a specific model (e.g. linear regression), I want to perform a stratified sample of my features based on the frequency of a specific crop variety in my data set. For example, if I split my data in 5 partitions (i.e. I use cross validation) and variety1 accounts for 50% of my observations, 50% of the observations in each partitioned training set should correspond to variety1. This is the code I have tried in Python using sklearn (version 0.23):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# build pd.DataFrame
varieties = np.concatenate([np.repeat("variety1", 10), 
                            np.repeat("variety2", 30), 
                            np.repeat("variety3", 60)])
columns = {"variety": varieties,
           "length": np.random.randint(30, 70, size=100),
           "width": np.random.randint(40, 50, size=100),
           "weight": np.random.random(100)*100 + 50}

df = pd.DataFrame(columns)

# stratified sampling
kf = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.2)

# fit model based on a cv splitter
lm = LinearRegression()
X = df.loc[:,"length":"width"]
y = df["weight"]
y_pred = cross_val_predict(lm, X, y, cv=kf.split(X, df["variety"]))
```

However, when I run this code I get the following error:

```
ValueError: cross_val_predict only works for partitions
```

This is a bit surprising for me because according to the [documentation of sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html) we can use a splitter in the cv argument of cross_val_predict. I know that I can use a for loop to accomplish what I want:

```
kf = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.2)
X = df.loc[:,"length":"width"]
y = df["weight"]
y_pred = np.zeros(y.size)
for train_idx, test_idx in kf.split(X, df["variety"]):
    #get subsets of variables from CV
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_idx], X.iloc[test_idx]
    y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_idx], y.iloc[test_idx]
    
    #fit model
    lm.fit(X_train, y_train)
    pred_vals = lm.predict(X_test)
    
    #store predicted values
    y_pred[test_idx] = pred_vals
```

However, I would prefer to use a cross_val_predict to make the code a bit more compact. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `StratifiedKFold` instead of `StratifiedShuffleSplit`.

The difference is that StratifiedKFold just shuffles and splits once, therefore the test sets do not overlap, while StratifiedShuffleSplit shuffles each time before splitting, and it splits n_splits times, the test sets can overlap and some data partitions are never a part of the test dataset, meaning there are no predictions for them.

You can read more at [Catbuilts's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52677641/11232272)