# StratifiedKFold vs KFold in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, k-fold

I use this code to test `KFold` and `StratifiedKFold`.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold,StratifiedKFold

X = np.array([
    [1,2,3,4],
    [11,12,13,14],
    [21,22,23,24],
    [31,32,33,34],
    [41,42,43,44],
    [51,52,53,54],
    [61,62,63,64],
    [71,72,73,74]
])

y = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1])

sfolder = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=4,random_state=0,shuffle=False)
floder = KFold(n_splits=4,random_state=0,shuffle=False)

for train, test in sfolder.split(X,y):
    print('Train: %s | test: %s' % (train, test))
print("StratifiedKFold done")

for train, test in floder.split(X,y):
    print('Train: %s | test: %s' % (train, test))
print("KFold done")
```

I found that `StratifiedKFold` can keep the proportion of labels, but `KFold` can't.

```
Train: [1 2 3 5 6 7] | test: [0 4]
Train: [0 2 3 4 6 7] | test: [1 5]
Train: [0 1 3 4 5 7] | test: [2 6]
Train: [0 1 2 4 5 6] | test: [3 7]
StratifiedKFold done
Train: [2 3 4 5 6 7] | test: [0 1]
Train: [0 1 4 5 6 7] | test: [2 3]
Train: [0 1 2 3 6 7] | test: [4 5]
Train: [0 1 2 3 4 5] | test: [6 7]
KFold done
```

It seems that `StratifiedKFold` is better, so should `KFold` not be used?

When to use `KFold` instead of `StratifiedKFold`?

Comment: Great answers out [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969390/difference-between-stratifiedkfold-and-stratifiedshufflesplit-in-sklearn), too (if you want to dive also in `StratifiedShuffleSplit` besides `StratifiedKFold` and `KFold`).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I think you should ask "***When to use StratifiedKFold instead of KFold?***".

You need to know what "**KFold**" and "**Stratified**" are first.

> KFold is a cross-validator that divides the dataset into k folds.

> Stratified is to ensure that each fold of dataset has the same
> proportion of observations with a given label.

So, it means that **StratifiedKFold** is the improved version of **KFold**

Therefore, the answer to this question is ***we should prefer StratifiedKFold over KFold when dealing with classification tasks with imbalanced class distributions***.

---

**FOR EXAMPLE**

Suppose that there is a dataset with 16 data points and imbalanced class distribution. In the dataset, 12 of data points belong to class A and the rest (i.e. 4) belong to class B. The ratio of class B to class A is 1/3. If we use **StratifiedKFold** and set k = 4, then, in each iteration, the training sets will include 9 data points from class A and 3 data points from class B while the test sets include 3 data points from class A and 1 data point from class B.

As we can see, the class distribution of the dataset is preserved in the splits by **StratifiedKFold** while **KFold** does not take this into consideration.

Comment: Did you mean "4 data points from class A..."?

Comment: Only difference between KFold and Stratified KFold is the balance in class distribution over each Fold, can you confirm?

Comment: @SmallChess Why 4 data points from class A, please clarify.

Answer (score 4):

```py
Assume Classification problem, Having 3 class(A,B,C) to predict.

Class  No_of_instance

 A           50 
 B           50
 C           50

**StratifiedKFold**

If data-set is  divided  into 5 fold. Then each fold will contains 10 instance from each class, i.e. no of instance per class is equal and follow  uniform distribution.

**KFold**

it will randomly took 30 instance and no of instance per class may or may not be equal or uniform.

**When to use**

Classification task use StratifiedKFold, and regression task use Kfold .
 
But if dataset contains  large number of instance, both StratifiedKFold and Kfold can be used in classification task.
```

Answer (score 1):

**[StratifiedKFold:](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html)** This cross-validation object is a variation of KFold that returns stratified folds. The folds are made by preserving the percentage of samples for each class

**[KFold:](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html)**  Split dataset into k consecutive folds.

`StratifiedKFold` is used when is need to `balance of percentage each class` in train & test. If not required `KFOld` is used.